# Accessing webpacker js in .js.erb views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline

I'm currently trying to switch from the asset pipeline to webpacker and I'm trying to figure out how to access the packaged javascript from .js.erb views.

All my forms look like this:

```rb
<% form_for ..., remote: true do %>
```

And my controllers all respond like this:

```rb
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

But inside the `.js.erb` templates (`create.js.erb` for the above example), I don't have access to anything from `app/javascript/packs/application.js` like I did when I was using the asset pipeline.

If my `create.js.erb` looks like this:

```js
$('form').prepend("<%=j form_errors(object) %>")
```

I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` error, because it can't access jQuery.

Here's my webpack environment file:

```js
# config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const coffee = require('./loaders/coffee')

const webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
}));

environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)
module.exports = environment
```

Any ideas how to access webpacked js in the .js.erb templates.

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in `application.js` and then try :-

```
// application.js

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()

require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")

window.jQuery = $;           // Add this line
window.$ = $;                // Add this line
```